# I want to change the font-family of the "Hello World" every second using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

It is changing the font family only one time while it should change the font family every second. please let me know what is the problem and why its not working.Thanks!

```
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="js_world">Hello World</h1>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){

        var x = document.getElementById("js_world");
        x.style.fontFamily = "helvetica";

        function changeFontFamily(){
            if (x.style.fontFamily === "helvetica"){
                x.style.fontFamily = "times new roman";
               }
            else if (x.style.fontFamily === "times new roman"){
                x.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
                }else if(x.style.fontFamily === "sans-serif"){
                      x.style.fontFamily = "helvetica"
                      }
         };  
     window.setInterval(changeFontFamily,1000);
     }
     </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `console.log(x.style.fontFamily)` It will clearly show you the problem

Comment: I added console.log(x.style.fontFamily) every time i changed the fontFamily. But it's only printing for the first time why it's not checking for else if statements?

Comment: Look at the value... you will see why `function changeFontFamily(){ console.log(x.style.fontFamily);`

Comment: Thanks all. It worked when I changed "times new roman" to "\"times new roman\"" . Could anyone let me know why it is so. why i need to use escape character here.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using this approach, which uses `setTimeout` and stores the possible fonts in an array.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var fonts = ["Courier New", "Times New Roman", "Roboto"];
var i = 0;
function changeFont(){
  if(i!=fonts.length){
    text.style.fontFamily=fonts[i];
    i++;
  }else{
    i=0;
  }
  setTimeout(changeFont, 1000);
}
changeFont();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

```html
<p id="text">Changing font? Wowza!</p>
```

If you insist on using your own, you can check out [Rap Sherlock's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802416/i-want-to-change-the-font-family-of-the-hello-world-every-second-using-javascr#65802515).

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var x = document.getElementById("js_world");
  x.style.fontFamily = "helvetica";
  function changeFontFamily(){
    console.log(x.style.fontFamily) // <-- debug to check fontFamily
    if (x.style.fontFamily === "helvetica"){
      x.style.fontFamily = "times new roman";
    } else if (x.style.fontFamily === "\"times new roman\"") { // <-- here your problem 
      x.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
    } else if(x.style.fontFamily === "sans-serif"){
      x.style.fontFamily = "helvetica"
    }
  }; 
  window.setInterval(changeFontFamily,1000); 
}
```

```html
<h1 id="js_world">Hello World</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The setInterval should be ok. You may use str.includes to check the fontfamily value after it is changed.
(please run the code snippet to see the result) :

```js
   var x = document.getElementById("js_world");
        x.style.fontFamily = "helvetica";
        

 function changeFontFamily(){

   var x = document.getElementById("js_world");
  var str=x.style.fontFamily;
       
       
       if (str.includes("helvetica")) {
       x.style.fontFamily = "times new roman";
               }
  
       if (str.includes("times new roman")) {
                x.style.fontFamily = "Verdana";
               }        
       if (str.includes("Verdana")) {
                    x.style.fontFamily = "helvetica";
                      }
         };  

         window.setInterval(changeFontFamily,2000);
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 id="js_world">Hello World</h1>
```